# How to display some portion of json data in a datlist control

Tags: c#, json

Hi Have a json data that I got from the service and I need to display that particular data in datalist.
Display Complete Json Data in the datalist is too easy...but I need to display first ten records in the datalist control and then when I reach the bottom of the page need to display the next ten with previous(total 20)
Just like Facebook posts....can any one suggest me..

Here I tried something like u said

```
public void BindGrid(int pageindex)
    {
        try
        {
            DataView dv;

            pageindex =Convert.ToInt32( hdnvalue.Value);
            string json = ClsUtility.HttpGet(url+"Services/Product.svc/GetProductsPageWise/"+pageindex);
            json = Regex.Unescape(json);
            dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '"', '.' }), typeof(DataTable));
            dv = dt.DefaultView;
            DataList1.DataSource = dv;
            DataList1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception Err)
        {

        }
        finally { }


    }
```

in the design page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageIndex = 1;
var pageCount;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -     $(window).height()) {
        document.getElementById('hdnvalue').value = pageIndex++

        alert(pageIndex++);

        GetRecords();
    }
});
function GetRecords() {
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            url: "Products.aspx/BindGrid",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                alert("gopal");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here my GetRecords method is not get executing

Comment: post your sample json data, are you working in asp.net or WPF?

Comment: its like ecommerce site JSON data has products Details i.e image,Name, Description...when i call d service i get complete data in the form of json..and all products are displaying in the page..But i just want to load first ten records and when I scrolleed down the next ten records like that

Comment: take a loot at this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-on-demand-data-in-GridView-on-scroll-using-ASPNet-and-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: pls go through the edited post

Comment: you should write a [WebMethod] on top of your method. and make the method statis.

Comment: I placed already its not executing

Comment: also make it a static method

Comment: you should separate that method into two different methods.you cannot use webcontrols inside static webmethod

Comment: still not getting executed i added code like datalist.datasource=bindgrid(1) and add webget and made static

Comment: can you please join chat?